# Remove Address 1 on register page in opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

how to remove Address 1, which is mandatory* field.

```
  <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-address-1"><?php echo $entry_address_1; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="address_1" value="<?php echo $address_1; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_address_1; ?>" id="input-address-1" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_address_1) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_address_1; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

on register.tpl page. I want address to be asked on checkout page.

Comment: you remove address 1 or only remove *. it's not compulsory field ?

Comment: Actually I want to remove all fields except (first name, last name, email, password and confirm password)

Comment: so, the address will be asked on checkout page.

Comment: I tried to remove it from register.tpl, and then remove validation from register.php(controller). But its not correct, we also need to modify Model files

Comment: no need from models and controllers file.

Comment: please upload with proper page screenshot. because we are easily understand. what is your actual need ?

Comment: ok. let me show you.

Comment: I would suggest you to hide the fields with simple CSS and add a default value using JS or the PHP controller, in order to pass the validation rules. The mandatory fields should not be deleted if you don't want to have other problems with the rest of the functionality.